# Removing the spacing around a TitledBorder

Tags: java, swing, titled-border

A `javax.swing.border.TitledBorder` introduces a spacing of 2 pixels around the edges of the border. This is quite annoying because it breaks the alignment with the components around.

How do you remove this spacing?

I'm looking for a solution that works for any look and feel.

Comment: you have to create own AbstractBorder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this edge width is hardcoded in TitledBorder class. So you can not remove this spacing.

```
public class TitledBorder extends AbstractBorder
{
    //...

    // Space between the border and the component's edge
    static protected final int EDGE_SPACING = 2;
}
```

But you can try to extend this class (override methods "void paintBorder(Component, Graphics, int, int, int, int)" or may be "Insets getBorderInsets(Component, Insets)") or implement your own border from scratch.

Comment: Thank you, I have extended TitledBorder and reimplemented paintBorder().

Answer (score 2):

That's not a real answer to your question but rather a suggestion: if you want to keep alignments across components then:

- don't use borders
- use only one panel for the whole dialog or frame
- use a `LayoutManager` that ensures correct alignment (suggestion: `DesignGridLayout`, but there are other good LayoutManagers as well)
- if you need to visually group components (the same way as a titled border), then introduce a row with a `JLabel` and a horizontal `JSeparator` (this one is a suggestion of Karsten Lentszch, from the JGoodies fame)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Getting rid of the titled borders is indeed a solution, unfortunately it's too disruptive for my application.